# Colouring grid bezier objects

Tags: r, r-grid

Grateful if someone could point me in the right direction for how to colour (fill) this grid-produced bezier object.  The `gpar` function in the documentation seems to have no effect.

```
require(grid)
x<-c(2,5,5,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,2,2)
y<-c(2,2,8,8,8,8,5,2,2,2,2,2)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(plotViewport(xscale=c(0, 10), yscale=c(0, 10)))
grid.xaxis(); grid.yaxis()
grid.bezier(x, y, id=rep(1:3,each=4), default.units="native", gp=gpar(fill='red'))
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you could use xsplineGrob instead?

Comment: Looks feasible but what a hideous undocumented `xsplineTest` function!  Am I right the `s` vector arguments are suppressing custom bezier points to force simple segment behaviour instead?

Comment: no idea, sorry, I've never really used either of those

Comment: @baptiste -- `xsplineTest` is a simple function defined in the Example section of `?xspline`. (And for what it's worth, it doesn't seem hideous to me, nor do I see why it should be documented!) Its argument `s` corresponds to/gets passed on to `xspline()`'s `shape=` argument.

Comment: Perhaps hideous is unfair, but IMO it makes comprehension more difficult than it needs to be. Why not just give the most minimal demo possible as most of R's examples do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution using `xspline` and  base R plot :

```
plot(x, y)
dd <- xspline(x, y, shape = 1,draw=FALSE)
xspline(x, y, shape = 1,draw=TRUE)
xx <- dd$x
yy <- dd$y
polygon(c(xx[1], xx, xx[1]), c(min(yy), yy, min(yy)),    
        col=rgb(1, 0, 0,0.5), border=NA)
```

[image]

You can also do the same in "grid" style , using  `grid.xspline` . here I am using `lattice` to avoid all viewport headache :

```
dat <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
library(lattice)
xyplot(y~x,data= dat , aspect = "xy",panel =function(x,y)
{

  grid.xspline(x,y,shape= 1,default.units="native",
     gp=gpar(fill='red'),open = FALSE)

})
```

[image]

Comment: This is great thanks agstudy. My only query is if you know why the slight change in the shape from my example - i.e. accentuating the bezier and adding curve to the top right?

Comment: @geotheory there is a difference because bezier uses an approximation of xspline.

Comment: Thanks again. Have amended data to make clearer. I think you need to change `xx[n]` to `xx[1]` in polygon to make it work.

Comment: @geotheory i fixed it. How did you amended data? Sorry ,  I don't get this point.

Comment: Nothing major I just changed a couple of the bezier point values so your code would produce more similar results to the `grid.bezier` - just to avoid confusion.